# select days date in between from_date and to_date table columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table data as :

```
ID       FROM_DATE     TO_DATE
1        01/02/2018    05/02/2018
2        06/02/2018    10/02/2018
```

I need to select data from that table as:

```
ID      Day_Date
1       01/02/2018
1       02/02/2018
1       03/02/2018
1       04/02/2018
1       05/02/2018
2       06/02/2018
2       07/02/2018
2       08/02/2018
2       09/02/2018
2       10/02/2018
```

so it is possible to get that result in oracle database ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `connect by level` clause with the contribution of `cross join` as :

```
with t(ID,from_date,to_date) as
(
 select 1, date'2018-02-01', date'2018-02-05' from dual union all
 select 2, date'2018-02-06', date'2018-02-10' from dual
)
select ID, min(from_date) + level - 1 as "Day_Date"
  from dual cross join t
 connect by level <= to_date - from_date + 1  
 group by ID, from_date, level
 order by ID;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/UAWV20904)

Answer (score 2):

Try inner joining a calendar table containing dates to cover everything in your data against your current table:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE - ROWNUM) dt
    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366
)

SELECT
    t.ID, d.dt AS Day_Date
FROM dates d
INNER JOIN yourTable t
    ON d.dt BETWEEN t.FROM_DATE AND t.TO_DATE
ORDER BY
    d.dt;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Great Done, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another variant could be using a pipelined table function with start and end date as input 
Package declaration:

```
create or replace package tst_pkg as 
  type xx is table of date; 
  function get_days (start_date date, end_date date) return xx pipelined; 
end tst_pkg;
```

Package body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY TST_PKG AS

  function get_days (start_date date, end_date date) return xx pipelined AS
  BEGIN
    for xx in 0 .. (end_date - start_date) loop 
      pipe row (trunc(start_date + xx)); 
    end loop; 
  END get_days;

END TST_PKG;
```

The query would be something like the one below

```
select id, column_value from emp, table(tst_pkg.get_days(start_date, end_date)) ;
```